# Trying to retrieve data from an API, but I cannot connect and I do not understand the error output

Tags: json, curl

I'm trying to retrieve a random quote from an API (in the form of a JSON file) using this command:

```
 curl -v  -i -X GET http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en
```

but I recieve the following output error:

> [1] 4009
>
> [2] 4010
>
> [3] 4011
>
> salpal@salpal-Aspire-E5-573G:~$ Error: wrong method.
>
> [1]   Done                    curl -X GET http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0>
>   /method=getQuote
>
> [2]-  Done                    key=457653
>
> [3]+  Done                    format=json

It says I am using the wrong method, but I am simply following the directions of the documentation specified here:

http://forismatic.com/en/api/

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you were missing the ?.

Try `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en`